# Need a second pair of eyes on my code - adding a point on a circle to match an existing point using a given an angle

Tags: trigonometry

First off, I am really just a programmer; I was a little conflicted as to where to ask this as the issue could easily be code related. That said I figured I'd start here. Also if possible, I'm not great with reading formulas or,well, math in general haha; it'd be fantastic if any explanations could dumbed down or stick to code if possible.

If this is a better question for stackoverflow, feel free to mention and I'll post there instead.

Anyways; the basic issue I'm having is - with a given angle I am trying to find x/y values so that I can add a new point to a drawing that lines up with an existing point.

let say we have

```
vec2 p1 = vec2(0.5,0); // lets say this is the origin
vec2 p2 = vec2(20,30);
```

I'd like to plot another point, lets call it p3, so that it's angle on a circle lines up with p2. I guess another way to try and explain - if I were to rotate p3 by a given angle, it should get drawn on the same spot as p2 (I hope that's clear enough of an explanation, I can try to reword it)

From what I can find, the basic formula should be

```
radius = sqrt((p2.x - p1.x)^2 + (p2.y - p1.y)^2)
p3.x = p1.x + (radius * cos(angle))
p3.y = p1.y + (radius * sin(angle))
```

My understanding is that,with the formula, p3 should get plotted onto the same x and y as p2. However when I draw this out, while both p2 and p3 do appear to lie on the same circle, the resulting x and y values appear to be very different between p2/p3.

I was hoping someone could help me try to understand the seemingly inconsistent values and what I could possibly be doing wrong or even point me in the right direction of what to search for.

Thank you very much!

I have a p5.js sketch here for demonstration
https://editor.p5js.org/sortofsleepy/sketches/smJ5Kl_GT

I can't add inline images yet but an image for reference (note you can also hit the play button in p5 to get the image as well and generate new ones if you tweak something)

[Issue I'm having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoXsC.png)

**Edit :** Solved! Thanks to David K for pointing me in the right direction and confirming what I was thinking(if you want to make an answer reply I can mark it as the correct solution).

Not that I expect this to be a common problem but just in case the concepts and ideas at least happens to be helpful for other problems,

To first explain the bigger problem, I was asked to write a unit test to confirm that if I rotate a matrix and project a point at a given angle from world space to screen space using that matrix, the value should = the value I would get if all points were in screen space to begin with and perform the same rotation operation.

Solution was to first, find the angle of a p2 on a circle. If you take that angle and apply it to p3 using the formula mentioned above, you get the same x and y values of p2. Finding that angle is

```
atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x)
```

If you take that and and re-apply it to the formula, but also add the angle you actually want to deal with, that appears to yield the correct solution that I needed. In other words

```
angle = <angle we're testing against, can be any value in radians>
p2Angle = atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x)
radius = sqrt((p2.x - p1.x)^2 + (p2.y - p1.y)^2)
p3.x = p1.x + (radius * cos(angle + p2Angle))
p3.y = p1.y + (radius * sin(angle + p2Angle))
```

There might be an edge case(s) I'm not thinking of but at the very least, this appears to solve my specific issue.

Comment: Wherever this question belongs it needs a picture showing p1, p2, the p3 you compute and the p3 you expect. I doubt that people want to read your javascript.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to place `p3` such that the angle formed by `pt2`, `pt1`, and `pt3` measures `angle`?

Comment: adding to @MatthewLeingang, with $p1$ as vertex?

Comment: And I agree with @EthanBolker: please draw and include a picture.

Comment: I agree that this is the wrong place for the question.

Comment: Apologies! I can't add inline images yet and you can get the image if you hit the play button on the p5 site; added image anyways and made a note about the play button.
Also tried to clarify the issue(or what I think is the issue).

I'll try asking on Stack too then

Comment: Playing the code just draws three points. It does not tell us what you want to see and how what is there is wrong. If you do ask elsewhere please delete here.

Comment: What does `p3 should have the same x/y as p2` mean? Does it mean `pt3.x/pt3.y = pt2.x/pt2.y`? or `pt3.x = pt2.x` and `pt3.x = pt2.y`?  The first doesn't sound like a good condition if `pt2.y` happens to be zero. The second also seems pointless, since then $p_3$ and $p_2$ are the same point. So it must be something else.

Comment: After your edit: you are saying: Input:  points  $p1$ and $p2$, and angle $\theta$. The points $p1$ and $p2$ determine a  circle $C$ centered on $p1$ and running through $p2$. Output: $p3$ a point on $C$,  such that rotating $p3$ by $\theta$ on $C$ would make $p3=p2$. Correct?

Comment: The formula ensures that `p3` and `p2` will be at the same distance from `p1`. Whether they are the same point depends on whether the `angle` value you used is the `angle` value that arrives at `p2`. You have no calculations in the program to determine the correct value of `angle`; you just put numbers into your program from somewhere. The reason the points don't line up is because those numbers (wherever they came from) are not mutually consistent that way.

Comment: MatthewLeingang - apologies, I should have used commas to avoid implying division. I meant p3.x = p2.x , p3.y = p2.y. I realize this does sound pointless; but this is just a part of a bigger issue I'm trying to solve. Not sure exactly of what to search for right now so figured I'd start by breaking down the problem into smaller chunks based on what I know at the moment.

Comment: peter a g - yes that sounds right, my understanding of the formula is that it "should" make p3 = p2, but clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: David K - that does make sense; that was kind of what I was leaning towards that as being possibly the issue; thanks for your input! I think I have something I can start to search for now

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to place $p_3$ such that the angle formed by $p_2$, $p_1$, and $p_3$ (with $p_1$ as the vertex) has measure $\theta$.

First, the math. If $p_1$ is the origin, you need to apply a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) $R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$ to $p_2$. Your code is only going to work if $p_2$ lies on the $x$-axis.

If $p_1$ is not the origin, you can translate $p_2$ to the origin by subtracting $p_1$, then rotate, then add it back. So
$$
   p_3 = R(p_2 - p_1)+p_1 
$$

Your code should read:

```
let x = cos(angle)*(pt2.x-pt1.x)-sin(angle)*(pt2.y-pt1.y) + pt1.x
let y = sin(angle)*(pt2.x-pt1.x)+cos(angle)*(pt2.y-pt1.y) + pt1.x
```

Comment: Appreciate the comment! Unfortunately I've run out of time this morning to try to see what happens with the code beyond writing this comment but will do so a little later. 

In the meantime based on your description it sounds like I was not quite clear in describing the problem - I tried to re-word a little and added an image to hopefully clarify.